# Is this normal, or is my XP-Pen tablet broken?

Tags: gimp, drawing-tablet

[image]

So whenever I do fast strokes to try to do smooth lines my tablet does this wierd jagged lines. I was using Gimp to test out my XP-Pen Deco v2 and it gives me these lines. Are these things normal? I had my pen dropped from 2-3 feet and my tablet between a wireless keyboard if that would break it, but I'm sure that XP-Pen pen tablets are not fragile at all. Can someone help me? I'm new to digital drawing BTW

Comment: Too many variables. Yes those strokes *can* be normal depending upon settings... or they can be a result of a problem... there's really no way for anyone here to know. This is ultimately tech support and off-topic. You might try an XP Pen tablet support forum or something. It's not unheard of for a dropped pen (even from 2-3 ft) to have some connection loosened internally if it falls in just the right way. Kind of like cracking a cell screen... you can drop it several times and be fine, but all it takes is one unlucky landing to crack the screen.

Comment: if it is the settings what do you reccomend to do to fix the broken lines?

Comment: I use neither Gimp nor an Xpen.. I use Photoshop and an Intuous... I can't give you any settings.

Comment: What are the "Brush dynamics" set to? Did you try with "Dynamics off"?

Comment: it was set to basic. Ill see if your suggestion works

Comment: It works but I basically lost my pen pressure function

Comment: Then it really looks like something is broken in your pen...

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Tech Unfortunately, tech support is off-topic here. Contact the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem till today. I disabled Windows Ink, and it worked perfectly. In the pen tablet menu, it's at the bottom left, next to Export Configuration. Hope this solves your problem!